# Проблема с Electron: Cannot find module './lib/jquery.min.js'

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

Пишу приложение на Electron и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при попытке подключить Jquery с помощью

window.$ = window.Jquery = require("./lib/jquery.min.js");

получаю следующую ошибку: Cannot find module './lib/jquery.min.js'. Вот директория, в которой находится html файл, и из которой должен запускаться Jquery.
[image]

Comment: Подключается скрипт тоже из html файла?

Comment: Проверьте права на чтение и попробуйте по абсолютному пути подключить.